# How to implement progress bar dialog in thymeleaf bootstrap with spring boot website?

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to implement a progress bar dialog in thymeleaf bootstrap with spring boot website.

Scenario: when I click on submit button for file uploading, the progress bar should display and go off when file uploading is completed.

I implemented this ajax call but it's not working:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: { value : value },
    url : 'result',
    beforeSend : function() { 
        $("#progressbarloader").show(); 
    },
    complete : function() { 
       $("#progressbarloader").hide(); 
    },
    success : function(data) {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: done the changes ..see if you can help

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick

I suppose that you are using bootstrap Progress bar

you can use a js thread in jquery where you change values of displayed progress

Here is a psoeudo code to help you

```
process = true;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: { value : value },
    url : 'result',
    beforeSend : function() { 
        $("#progressbarloader").show();
        value = 0;
        finalValue = 100;
        while(process){
           // create new thread with timeout 700 ms
               // thread function
                 // value = value + (finalValue-value)/4;
                 // change progress bar value using jquery
        }
    },
    complete : function() { 
       $("#progressbarloader").hide(); 
    },
    success : function(data) {
        console.log('success');
        value = 0;
        process = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I m a javadevelopper I dont have all the javascript skills to write your code but this should help you